# The correct signature of a utility function to Array class: Comparable<E> or Comparable<? super E>?

Tags: java, comparable, type-bounds

I'm trying to write a utility function to the Array class.

The function should return the minimum element for all kinds of comparable types.

My question is which signature should the function has:

1. `public static <E> E min (Comparable**<E>**[] arr)`
2. `public static <E> E min (Comparable**<? super E>**[] arr)`

In Java arrays are variants and that means that if B extends A so A[] and B[] are related too, but `ArrayList<A>` and `ArrayList<B>` don't have the same connection.

This is the full code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <E> E min (Comparable<E>[] arr){

    E min= null;

    if(arr.length > 0)          
        min = (E) arr[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {

        if( (arr[i].compareTo((E) min)) < 0)
            min = (E) arr[i];
    }

    return min; 
}
```

Comment: I have two class `A` implements `Comparable` `A` and `B` extends `A`

When the signature is `Comparable<? super E>` then the call (from main) to:

```
A aArr[] = new A[] {new A(1), new B(2), new B(-1)};
B bb = min(aArr);
```

is a compiling error: `cannoot convert from ...A to ... B`, but when the signature of min() is `Comparable<? super E>` then the same call is just fine.

Thanks

Comment: If your question is closed, you can accept the answer. Or let us know, if you are still looking for a solution or clarification

Answer (score 1):

The second signature works because A is superclass of class B, whereas it suits wildcard condition  `? super B`.

If you want your function to return minimum value of **any** comparable typed array, you just need.

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> min (E[] arr)
```

This will allow you to use the method for operating all kind of arrays, values of which have comparable type. In your case, you want A and B to be related. So you should also allow your method to take parameter of class E and it's superclasses. However, it is only needed, when you try to cast A to B, as in your example. That makes you want your method to take superclasses of E (as A is superclass of B) and still return value of type E.

```
public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> min (E[] arr)
```

Comment: But again the call: 'B bb = min(aArr);' get the same error... ,but <E extends Comparable<? super E>> work fine

Comment: @HodiyaEyal I guess the problem, that you cannot make B variable hold a reference to object of type A, since A is not necessarily instance of B, let me think about this a bit

Comment: @HodiyaEyal I edited my answer. So yeah, in your case you should also take care of super types. Note that in opposite situation the code will not work, so for `A=min(arrB)` you should use `? extends E`. It depends on what hierarchy and class relation you choose to use

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the signatures is a "correct" signature for this method, IMO. The correct signature is to accept a `E[]`, where `E extends Comparable<? super E>`:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> E min (E[] arr){

    E min= null;

    if(arr.length > 0)
        min = arr[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {

        if( (arr[i].compareTo(min)) < 0)
            min = arr[i];
    }

    return min;
}
```

Your current implementation makes an incorrect assumption that "classes that implement `Comparable<T>` must be `T` or a subclass of `T`". This is not necessarily true. This is why you have to suppress those warnings.

Anyway, back to your actual problem. At the caller's side, you are doing `B bb = min(aArr)`. In the `Comparable<E>` case, the error appears because the compiler could not infer what `E` should be. It can't be `A` because `A` can't be assigned to a variable of type `B`. It can't be `B` either, because you are giving it a `A[]`, which is not a `Comparable<B>[]`.

When you changed it to `Comparable<? super E>`, `E` *can* be `B` now. Since `A[]` is compatible with `Comparable<? super B>`.

But this only works in a really "hacky" way, because you are technically casting every element in the array to a `B`, since `E` is `B`, and because of how Java generics are erased, this doesn't fail.

The root of your problem really lies in the line `B bb = min(aArr)`. You are making a possibly wrong assumption that the minimum of `aArr` is of type `B`. Why are you so sure? It could be an `A` as well, right? With my solution above, you need to cast the result to `B` if you are so sure that it is `B`:

```
B bb = (B)min(aArr);
```